# How to reduce size of image in Gmail Addon Using Card Services

Tags: image, google-apps-script, add-on, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm developing the Gmail addon through card services. My login screen contains below widgets :

1. Language Dropdown
2. Logo
3. Login Form

I had provided the code for that.

```
    // Create a language dropdown
    var languageDropdown = CardService.newSelectionInput()
        .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
        .setTitle('Language')
        .setFieldName('language')
        .addItem('English', 'en', true)
        .addItem('Hindi', 'hi', false);

    // Create a logo image
    let cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1CropStyle1 = CardService.newImageCropStyle()
        .setAspectRatio(1)
        .setImageCropType(CardService.ImageCropType.SQUARE);

    let cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1BorderStyle1 = CardService.newBorderStyle()
        .setType(CardService.BorderType.NO_BORDER)
        .setCornerRadius(4);

    let cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1 = CardService.newImageComponent()
        .setImageUrl('https://source.unsplash.com/featured/320x320?nature&sig=3')
        .setCropStyle(cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1CropStyle1)
        .setBorderStyle(cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1BorderStyle1);

    let cardSection1Grid1Item1 = CardService.newGridItem()
        .setTextAlignment(CardService.HorizontalAlignment.START)
        .setLayout(CardService.GridItemLayout.TEXT_BELOW)
        .setImage(cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1);

    let cardSection1Grid1 = CardService.newGrid()
        .setNumColumns(1)
        .addItem(cardSection1Grid1Item1);

    // Create a login form
    var loginForm = CardService.newCardSection()
        .setHeader('Login Form')
        .addWidget(CardService.newTextInput()
            .setFieldName('Text')
        )
        .addWidget(CardService.newTextInput()
            .setFieldName('email')
        )
        .addWidget(CardService.newTextInput()
            .setFieldName('password')
        );

    const card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .addSection(
            CardService.newCardSection()
                .addWidget(languageDropdown)
                .addWidget(cardSection1Grid1)
        )
        .addSection(loginForm).build()

    return card;
```

[image: Login Screen]

I just want to **reduce** the size of the image. like we do in HTML using height and weight. Here height and weight are not supported because it's a card service and we have a limitation of CSS.

So is there any other way to reduce the size of the logo?

can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score -1):

Try following code:

```
// create your logo image
let cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1CropStyle1 = CardService.newImageCropStyle()
    .setAspectRatio(1)
    .setImageCropType(CardService.ImageCropType.SQUARE);

let cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1BorderStyle1 = CardService.newBorderStyle()
    .setType(CardService.BorderType.NO_BORDER)
    .setCornerRadius(4);

let cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1 = CardService.newImageComponent()
    .setImageUrl('https://source.unsplash.com/featured/320x320?nature&sig=3')
    .setPixelSize(100, 100) // Set the width and height here
    .setCropStyle(cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1CropStyle1)
    .setBorderStyle(cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1BorderStyle1);

let cardSection1Grid1Item1 = CardService.newGridItem()
    .setTextAlignment(CardService.HorizontalAlignment.START)
    .setLayout(CardService.GridItemLayout.TEXT_BELOW)
    .setImage(cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1);

let cardSection1Grid1 = CardService.newGrid()
    .setNumColumns(1)
    .addItem(cardSection1Grid1Item1);
```

in the code above, I've added the setPixelSize method to the cardSection1Grid1Item1Image1 image component and you can specify the width and height in pixels to control the size of the image.

Comment: There is no setImageSize() method

Comment: There is not any method name setPixelSize()